# RHEL 9.1 - SELinux is preventing /usr/local/bin/php from read access on the file /web/inc/init_db.inc.php

Tags: rhel, php, selinux, linux-audit

i want to solve this problem what SELinux says.

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/local/bin/php from read access on the file /web/inc/init_db.inc.php.
```

output from console is:

```
[root@rhel ~]# ausearch -c 'php' --raw | audit2allow -M my-php
compilation failed:
my-php.te:15:ERROR 'syntax error' at token 'mlsconstrain' on line 15:

mlsconstrain file { ioctl read lock execute execute_no_trans } ((h1 dom h2 -Fail-) or (t1 != mcs_constrained_type -Fail-) ); Constraint DENIED
mlsconstrain file { write setattr append unlink link rename } ((h1 dom h2 -Fail-) or (t1 != mcs_constrained_type -Fail-) ); Constraint DENIED
/usr/bin/checkmodule: error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
```

I never encountered this problem before what should i do ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75440767/rhel-selinux-access-control-errors

Comment: What is the context of your php files? Can you paste the output of `ls -lahZ /web/inc/init_db.inc.php` please?